# Change in duration for failed login attempt by setting pam_faildelay.so delay is not taking effect

Tags: linux, authentication, centos7, pam

I have changed the delay value using "pam_faildelay.so delay" but the delay which I added 300 ms is not taking effect. For failed login attempts still I can see 2 seconds delay.

Below is rule which I added in system-auth file,

`auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=300000`

Can any one help me how to reduce the delay for failed login attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your `pam_unix` rule. It must contain `nodelay`, otherwise `pam_unix` will apply two seconds delay on failed attempt.